# Transaction is successful but nft photo is empty

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, etherscan, hardhat, erc-721

I have issue i succesfully minted and send nft but when I checking this nft on etherscan i see nft transaction but don't see img same on metamask i don't see any kind of nft or any nft photos

Attachments:

[image]

[image]
[image]

Code 1

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.1;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract REALESTATE is ERC721, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;

    constructor() ERC721("RealEsate", "RE") {}

    function _baseURI() internal pure override returns (string memory) {
        return
            "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmToLt8pdvBAMvX3iTvcig6Tw4Sh3sP5uGdK19o7asV74B";
    }

    function safeMint(address to) public onlyOwner {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        tokenId = 0;
    }
}
```

code 2

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.1;
import "./nftestate.sol";

contract BidContract is REALESTATE {
    struct Bid {
        address bidder;
        uint amount;
    }
    address public ownerr;
    uint public highestBid;
    address public highestBidder;
    event newbid(uint256 indexed highestBid, address indexed highestBidder);

    mapping(address => Bid) public bids;

    constructor() {
        ownerr = msg.sender;
    }

    function hisghestbidcheck() public view returns (uint256) {
        return highestBid;
    }

    function bid() public payable {
        require(msg.value > highestBid, "Bid too low");

        if (highestBidder != address(0)) {
            payable(highestBidder).transfer(highestBid);
        }

        highestBid = msg.value;
        highestBidder = msg.sender;
        bids[msg.sender] = Bid(msg.sender, msg.value);
        emit newbid(highestBid, highestBidder);
    }

    function endAuction() public {
        require(msg.sender == ownerr, "Only owner can end auction");
        require(highestBidder != address(0), "No bids received");

        payable(ownerr).transfer(highestBid);
        highestBid = 0;
        safeMint(highestBidder);
        highestBidder = address(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On mainnet Etherscan, NFT images take some time to be indexed, with different indexing priorities such as if your token is [updated](https://info.etherscan.com/how-to-update-token-information-on-token-page/) or not.

Testnets explorers such as [Sepolia](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/) or [Goerli](https://goerli.etherscan.io/) unfortunately do not have support for NFT images.

Answer (score 1):

There is something you need to understand when working with ERC721 contracts. There are 2 types of NFTs you generate through this standard:

1. **Multiple NFTs:** Something similar to `Bored Apes`. In this case, the `baseURI()` function contains the link to the metadata of all the images. Notice that it contains the metadata of the image, and not the image itself.

> BaseURI of Bored Apes:
> ipfs://QmeSjSinHpPnmXmspMjwiXyN6zS4E9zccariGR3jxcaWtq

2. **Single NFT:** Only 1 NFT is minted through the NFT contract. Since it doesn't necessarily need uri to a folder, you can directly point to the metadata file. Therefore, you don't need to use `baseUri` in this case. You can explicitly set the `tokenURI` of the NFT.

Now talking about your contract, you are directly inputting the link to your image in your baseURi, which is wrong. baseURI needs a link to the metadata file, not the image itself. Second, since you are minting just 1 NFT, you don't need baseURI necessarily.

**Metadata format:**

```
 {
  "image": "ipfs://QmPbxeGcXhYQQNgsC6a36dDyYUcHgMLnGKnF8pVFmGsvqi",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "Mouth",
      "value": "Grin"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Clothes",
      "value": "Vietnam Jacket"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Background",
      "value": "Orange"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Eyes",
      "value": "Blue Beams"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Fur",
      "value": "Robot"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Possible Modification:**

```
function safeMint(address to, string memory _tokenURI) public onlyOwner {
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();            
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
        
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, _tokenURI)
        tokenId = 0;
    }
```

See ERC721UriStorage.sol. It will help you.

Comment: i modified code but photo is still blank i think on testnets all nft photos are blank

Comment: Share your code and transaction

Comment: code:
    ```constructor() ERC721("RealEsate", "RE") {}

    uint256 tokenId = 0;
    mapping(uint256 => string) private _tokenURIs;

    function _setTokenURI(
        uint256 tokenId,
        string memory _tokenURI
    ) internal virtual {
        require(
            _exists(tokenId),
            "ERC721URIStorage: URI set of nonexistent token"
        );
        _tokenURIs[tokenId] = _tokenURI;
    }

    function safeMint(address to, string memory _tokenURI) public onlyOwner {
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, _tokenURI);
    }```

Comment: and tx hash on Sepolia Testnet:0x0fca79af799260b10f4478a67c4dd301487b96abdf3d911d387458983187c2ae

Comment: You can dm me directly on dc:```Xardesso#9566```

Comment: @MarcinŁętowski Just added you

Comment: I give you details about error on dc